# Converting Hex NCR text representations to Unicode in Python

Tags: python, unicode, character-encoding, python-unicode, ncr

I have a string parsed from a web page originally in chinese as:

```
若き葉末には風が立ち 森は翡翠の息を返す 雲の切れ間から注ぐ 光に君を見初めん

碧き瞳のほほえむとき そは鐘のひびき胸に打つ さしのべた腕に絡む 蔦の葉に君を逃す

残る　香り 水面をかけゆく恋の舟 つかの間の波に　揺られ

やさしき幻影　心に映るその姿よ 永遠なる君に　想いを捧げん

若き葉末には風は眠り 森は密やかに息を止む 抱きしめた腕のなかで 静かに君は消えゆく

月は　満ちて 黄金の羽根が舞いおちる 我はただひとり森に

祈りたまえや
```

However in the process of parsing it, it was converted into Hex NCR string in the following form:

```
&#x82E5;&#x304D;&#x8449;&#x672B;&#x306B;&#x306F;&#x98A8;&#x304C;&#x7ACB;&#x3061;\n&#x68EE;&#x306F;&#x7FE1;&#x7FE0;&#x306E;&#x606F;&#x3092;&#x8FD4;&#x3059;\n&#x96F2;&#x306E;&#x5207;&#x308C;&#x9593;&#x304B;&#x3089;&#x6CE8;&#x3050;\n&#x5149;&#x306B;&#x541B;&#x3092;&#x898B;&#x521D;&#x3081;&#x3093;\n\n&#x78A7;&#x304D;&#x77B3;&#x306E;&#x307B;&#x307B;&#x3048;&#x3080;&#x3068;&#x304D;\n&#x305D;&#x306F;&#x9418;&#x306E;&#x3072;&#x3073;&#x304D;&#x80F8;&#x306B;&#x6253;&#x3064;\n&#x3055;&#x3057;&#x306E;&#x3079;&#x305F;&#x8155;&#x306B;&#x7D61;&#x3080;\n&#x8526;&#x306E;&#x8449;&#x306B;&#x541B;&#x3092;&#x9003;&#x3059;\n\n&#x6B8B;&#x308B;&#x3000;&#x9999;&#x308A;\n&#x6C34;&#x9762;&#x3092;&#x304B;&#x3051;&#x3086;&#x304F;&#x604B;&#x306E;&#x821F;\n&#x3064;&#x304B;&#x306E;&#x9593;&#x306E;&#x6CE2;&#x306B;&#x3000;&#x63FA;&#x3089;&#x308C;\n\n&#x3084;&#x3055;&#x3057;&#x304D;&#x5E7B;&#x5F71;&#x3000;&#x5FC3;&#x306B;&#x6620;&#x308B;&#x305D;&#x306E;&#x59FF;&#x3088;\n&#x6C38;&#x9060;&#x306A;&#x308B;&#x541B;&#x306B;&#x3000;&#x60F3;&#x3044;&#x3092;&#x6367;&#x3052;&#x3093;\n\n&#x82E5;&#x304D;&#x8449;&#x672B;&#x306B;&#x306F;&#x98A8;&#x306F;&#x7720;&#x308A;\n&#x68EE;&#x306F;&#x5BC6;&#x3084;&#x304B;&#x306B;&#x606F;&#x3092;&#x6B62;&#x3080;\n&#x62B1;&#x304D;&#x3057;&#x3081;&#x305F;&#x8155;&#x306E;&#x306A;&#x304B;&#x3067;\n&#x9759;&#x304B;&#x306B;&#x541B;&#x306F;&#x6D88;&#x3048;&#x3086;&#x304F;\n\n&#x6708;&#x306F;&#x3000;&#x6E80;&#x3061;&#x3066;\n&#x9EC4;&#x91D1;&#x306E;&#x7FBD;&#x6839;&#x304C;&#x821E;&#x3044;&#x304A;&#x3061;&#x308B;\n&#x6211;&#x306F;&#x305F;&#x3060;&#x3072;&#x3068;&#x308A;&#x68EE;&#x306B;\n\n&#x7948;&#x308A;&#x305F;&#x307E;&#x3048;&#x3084;
```

I want to convert this string into its appropriate unicode format.

From my research I have been able to gather that for example `&#x4E00;` maps to the unicode string `b'\\u4e00'`.

This can be manually done by stripping `&#x` and prefixing a `\\u` to the beginning of the string along with making the whole thing lowercase and converting to a bytestring by adding a `b` before the string.
This is done in this [repo](https://github.com/maximilianh/maxtools/blob/master/lib/unicodeConvert.py) but through the use of the inefficient eval function through code such as `eval("b'\\u4e00")`.

[EDIT: The above para is incorrect. It is not a bytestring but a unicode string as present in python2. The correct mapping would be `&#x4E00;` -> `u'\u4e00'`]

Is there a better way to do this? Considering edge cases where these hex map strings can be present in the middle of regular text such as here:

```
Je me levais t&#xF4;t
Travailler en homme
Je me souviens du go&#xFB;t
Du caf&#xE9; br&#xFB;lant
Dans la tasse rouge
Et la femme qui dort
Les portes ouvertes de la grande usine
Bouffaient nos fils le jour de leurs quinze ans
On se levait t&#xF4;t
Sortis de nos draps
On se retrouvait en bas
Les rues du village s'allumaient d'un coup
A six heures moins le quart
Les portes ouvertes de la grande usine
Bouffaient nos fils bien avant leurs quinze ans
On se l&#xE8;ve trop t&#xF4;t
On sait plus quoi faire
Dans le caf&#xE9; des vieux
Les mains dans nos poches
Cachent nos poings noirs
Y'a plus qu'&#xE0; qui change pas
Les portes sont ferm&#xE9;es
Y'a plus de feu qui gronde
L'usine a tout vomi d'un seul coup
Pourquoi on fait &#xE7;a
Pourquoi &#xE7;a m'fait &#xE7;a
Pourquoi on nous fait &#xE7;a &#xE0; nous
```

I am dealing with a large set of data where such characters can be strewn anywhere, and I need a meaningful way to deal with them.

So is there any better way to do this? Ideally one that is supported inherently by python.

If someone has a solution to my problem here, I will be immensely grateful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the `html` module in the standard library:

```
>>> import html
>>> html.unescape('Je me levais t&#xF4;t')
'Je me levais tôt'
>>> html.unescape('&#x82E5;&#x304D;&#x8449;&#x672B;&#x306B;&#x306F;')
'若き葉末には'
```

The result is a Unicode string (type `str` in Python 3).
Note that the `b'...'` notation is for byte strings.
The literal `b'\\u4e00'` in your example does not make much sense, since it is a byte string with 6 characters (\, u, 4, e, 0, 0).
You probably meant `'\u4e00'` (or `u'\u4e00'` in Python 2), which is a single-character Unicode string.

Comment: Thanks this works! And you're right about the unicode string - I've reflected it in an edit. The original mapping is the unicode `u'\\u4e00'` in python2.